# How to find all matches in linq list between 2 numbers

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of persons where one propery is a number as string, I would like to find all matches in that list that matches 2 numbers (a range).

```
    public class car
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string No { get; set; } 
    }


    public void test()
    {
        var myList = new List<car>
        {
            new car {Name = "Volvo", No = "10"},
            new car {Name = "Volvo", No = "20"},
            new car {Name = "Volvo", No = "30"},
            new car {Name = "Volvo", No = "40"},
            new car {Name = "Volvo", No = "50"},
            new car {Name = "Volvo", No = "60"}
        };

        var startNumber = 10;
        var EndNumber = 30;


    }
```

How can I filter out all the matches in the myList where No is within `startNumber` and `EndNumber` ?

Comment: You might want to consider changing the `No` property of the `car` class to an `int` instead of a `string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to parse the number to integer and then compare the range. You can also use `Int.TryParse` to save yourself from the exception. To do the parsing once, make an anonymous type and then query like:

```
int temp;
var query = myList.Select(r => new 
                            { 
                                Car = r, 
                                NumericNo = int.TryParse(r.No, out temp) ? temp : 0 //or -1 for invalid values
                            })
    .Where(r => r.NumericNo >= start && r.NumericNo <= end)
    .Select(r => r.Car);
```

You may also follow the [General Naming Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 4):

This is a pretty straightforward solution:

```
myList
    .Where(car => startNumber <= int.Parse(car.No) && int.Parse(car.No) <= EndNumber)
    .ToList();
```

**Note:** If we can't assume `No` will only contains Natural numbers, than using `int.TryParse` will be a better alternative than `int.Parse`.

**Remarks:**

1. I highly recommend you to save `No` as `int` rather than `string`.
2. Also don't be cheap on Property names, If you will use `Number` or `LicensePlate` it will be a little longer, but more concise.
3. You should follow .NET naming conventions by using class names with Capital letters. e.g: `Car`, `Animal`
4. First letter in `Local variables` should be lower cased. e.g: `endNumber`
5. It's a good practice to avoid `var` when using Primitive variables like `int`, `double` etc`

Comment: This seems like a right answer, not sure why it has been downvoted, +1 to counter that.

Comment: You have your comparison operator  for the start backwards.  You want `startNumber <=`

Comment: @Habib, The operator should be backwards.

Comment: @juharr, It was, in the original post, but it was edited (not by me), I've reedited it back to the original.

Comment: @Habib, No problem mate :), I've read it at `Code Complete - 2nd Edition` to start aligning compression in this order, to be more natural.